# Can not launch or re-install Quicklisp: ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM::STAMP undefined

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp, asdf

I broke my CL environment. I can run `sbcl` but I can't re-run or re-install Quicklisp (I simply deleted the directory `~/quicklisp/` and would like to start over properly). I get the following error:

```
* (load #p"~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")
While evaluating the form starting at line 129, column 0
  of #P"~/quicklisp/setup.lisp":

debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10019B67B3}>:
  The function ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM::STAMP<= is undefined.
```

The [line 129](https://github.com/quicklisp/quicklisp-client/blob/master/setup.lisp#L129) isn't of big interest, or so it seems.

Same trying to re-install Quicklisp.

ASDF version 3.2.1, SBCL 1.3.19.

What can be the cause of this ?

Or how can I *totally* and properly start over ? (thinking about hidden .fasl files or something).

Thanks !

edit: it downloads asdf 2.26

```
* (quicklisp-quickstart:install)

; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/client/quicklisp.sexp">
; 0.82KB
==================================================
838 bytes in 0.00 seconds (818.36KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/client/2017-03-06/quicklisp.tar">
; 250.00KB
==================================================
256,000 bytes in 0.09 seconds (2941.18KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/client/2015-09-24/setup.lisp">
; 4.94KB
==================================================
5,054 bytes in 0.00 seconds (0.00KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/asdf/2.26/asdf.lisp">
; 194.07KB
==================================================
198,729 bytes in 0.08 seconds (2553.57KB/sec)While evaluating the form starting at line 129, column 0
  of #P"/home/vince/quicklisp/setup.lisp":

debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10019B68B3}>:
  The function ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM::STAMP<= is undefined.
```

Comment: Did you install quicklisp using apt? If so, maybe you want to try using: `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove cl-quicklisp`. (source: http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/c/cl-quicklisp/uninstall/index.html)

Comment: Frorm the first look, it seems like an incompatible ASDF version.  SBCL brings its own, is there another installed?

Comment: @pdoherty926 I had not used `--auto-remove` (for cl-quicklisp and slime) but it is the same. @Svante I added a trace, `quicklisp-quickstart:install` downloads ASDF 2.26, is it normal ? In sbcl I can see I have ASDF 3.2.1. Don't know where it comes from :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it thanks to a nice ASDF warning message, trying to install a roswell utility:

> Install Script for sbcl-bin...
>   WARNING:
>      You are using ASDF version 3.3.1 (probably from (require "asdf") or loaded
>      by quicklisp) and have an older version of ASDF 3.2.1 registered at
>      #P"/home/vince/bacasable/portacle/build/asdf/asdf.asd". Having an ASDF
>      installed and registered is the normal way of configuring ASDF to upgrade
>      itself, and having an old version registered is a configuration error. ASDF
>      will ignore this configured system rather than downgrade itself. In the
>      future, you may want to either: (a) upgrade this configured ASDF to a newer
>      version, (b) install a newer ASDF and register it in front of the former in
>      your configuration, or (c) uninstall or unregister this and any other old
>      version of ASDF from your configuration. Note that the older ASDF might be
>      registered implicitly through configuration inherited from your system
>      installation, in which case you might have to specify
>      :ignore-inherited-configuration in your in your
>      ~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf or other source-registry
>      configuration file, environment variable or lisp parameter. Indeed, a likely
>      offender is an obsolete version of the cl-asdf debian or ubuntu package,
>      that you might want to upgrade (if a recent enough version is available) or
>      else remove altogether (since most implementations ship with a recent asdf);
>      if you lack the system administration rights to upgrade or remove this
>      package, then you might indeed want to either install and register a more
>      recent version, or use :ignore-inherited-configuration to avoid registering
>      the old one. Please consult ASDF documentation and/or experts.

So it was because of a build of Portacle, which I deleted and it's fine now. ~~I don't know why it interfered with me though~~ I had a too broad `(pushnew "~/bacasable/" asdf:*central-registry* :test #'equal)` in my `.sbclrc` (but it seems I had the pb with this line commented out…).

So looking for a solution would be: try to install a roswell utility (ros install sbcl-bin), look where you have asdf.lisp files (with `locate`), and follow ASDF warnings.

Thanks ASDF for the nice warning !